# How to create trigger when Insert and update table for checking if the inserted values respect case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to create trigger to check if a value like age is up to 18 when insert and update table but I don't know syntax, if someone can give me the syntax or reference to great course, I will be appreciated!

Comment: Storing age is usually the wrong thing to do. You are guaranteed that within a year of recording it, it's out of date, but you do not know when during that year. Storing date of birth doesn't suffer this issue and *deriving* age from DOB is relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is to CHECK and allow only ages > 18 into the table. You can use CHECK Constraints.

Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE People(NAME VARCHAR(100),AGE TINYINT,CHECK (AGE>18))
```

Success:

```
INSERT INTO People
SELECT 'A',20
```

Failure:

```
INSERT INTO People
SELECT 'A',17
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the CHECK constraint "CK__People__AGE..". The conflict occurred
>   in database "GraphExample", table "dbo.People", column 'AGE'.